# Getting list of values from column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, list

I have one `"column D"` with a b c values for my entities (1-2-3-4).
Something like that :

```
 1. b
 2. c
 3. c
 4. e
 5. j
 6. b
```

I would like to generate a list of each different value of `"column D"`. so I would have b,c,e,j. How can I perform this?

Comment: You could run `dissolve` and set the tool to dissolve by that column.

Comment: Do you want to create a column with the values?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

Use the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) with this expression:

```
array_to_string(
    array_distinct(
        array_agg(expression:="column D")
        )
    )
```

This expression utilizes the following functions: [`array_to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-to-string), [`array_distinct()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-distinct), and [`array_agg()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-agg).

Answer (score 6):

You can create a virtual layer to fetch the distinct values

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "column D"
FROM myLayer;
```

or to get it as a single list

```sql
SELECT group_concat(nme, ', ') 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT "column D" as nme 
  FROM myLayer
)
```

[image]

Comment: Docs : https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/ and https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-distinct/

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI2nN.png

Comment: @tonyduky your screenshot reveals you are entering the query as an expression, not as a virtual layer. See edited post for a picture of where/what it should look like